# Harmonic nesting: How often nodes of different sin waves line up with each other?

Tags: harmonic-analysis, harmonic-functions, wave-equation, harmonic-numbers, wavelets

I apologize if this is elementary.

I'm trying to figure out how often the nodes of different sine waves line up with each other. As in, when $y = 0$ for different functions.

I've been using Desmos to try to figure this out inductively. So I saw, in the case of two waves:
\begin{align}
 y &= \sin x \\
 y &= \sin .5x
\end{align}
The nodes will line up every $2 \pi$.

I also saw that, in the case of two waves:
\begin{align}
 y &= \sin x \\
 y &= \sin .7x
\end{align}
The waves line up every $10 \pi$.

How do I figure out when these two waves line up?
\begin{align}
 y &= \sin x \\
 y &= \sin 0.71x
\end{align}

And, ideally, how does one generalize to knowing when 3 or more waves' nodes synchronize?

Thank you! I'm trying to evaluate a theory of neural synchrony.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $\sin x = 0$ if $x = k\pi$ for some integer $k$, so as a consequence we have $\sin 0.71x = 0$ if $0.71x = k\pi$ for some integer $k$.

If we want both of these things to happen for the same value of $x$, then we want integers $k$ and $\ell$ such that $x = k\pi$ and $0.71x = \ell\pi$. But then, we have $0.71k \pi = \ell\pi$, or $71k = 100\ell$. Since $\gcd(71, 100) = 1$, this happens when $k = 100m$ and $\ell = 71m$, for some integer $m$.

This means that the nodes of $\sin 0.71x$ and $\sin x$ will line up when $x = 100m \pi$: the common nodes will be $100\pi$ apart.

Comment: Misha, this is much more direct than I expected.